# How to get lines around text with break in between?

Tags: html, css, border

I have to add lines around the text where there are spaces in between so that it is not just a matter of adding border all the way around. Below is what is expected, but I am not sure where to start to modify the border such that it has gaps like the image shows.

In terms of the spacing and border,

- They have to be `10px` from the side. So the top one should be `10px` from the right side. The bottom one should be `10px` from the left.
- The spaces have can be anywhere from `8px` or `16px` in width.
- The border should be either `1px` or `3px` based on what is possible.

For the solution, if more html elements are needed or if we have to target any css pseudo elements, then that is fine.

**Desired output:**

[image: border around text]

I tried the following, but can't get it to work like the image.

```css
.box { 
  border-top:    1px solid black;
  border-right:  1px solid black; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text inside
</div>
```

Comment: So, just random spaces along the border? 2, 3, 5? Any length? Anything specific?? Only one div? Extra html allowed? Extra css ok?

Comment: @wazz i did update the question with more specifics. Does that help?

Comment: Yes tnx. I'm not sure of the best approach other than adding extra divs with and without borders as needed. Check back for other replies.

Comment: @wazz okay, i was not sure either so hence the question. I am open to adding more elements if needed.

Comment: border-image or backgound-gradient are the first 2 options i see

Comment: Temani to the rescue again.

Comment: @G-Cyr you could also use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements on additional divs around the main content (mainly if you also want to fill the gaps with text) like here https://codepen.io/the_human_brian/pen/vOrbBG

Comment: @peterxz spare the pseudo untill you know you do not need them ;) bg-gradient can also be animated https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IGliC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use gradient

```css
.box { 
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-right:2px solid;
  border-left:2px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to left ,#000 10px,transparent 10px 30px,#000 0) top,
    linear-gradient(to right,#000 10px,transparent 10px 30px,#000 0) bottom;
  background-size:100% 2px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text inside
</div>
```

With CSS variable to make it easy to adjust:

```css
.box { 
  --b:2px;  /* Thickness of border */
  --g:10px; /* The gap */
  --s:10px; /* The offset of the gap */
  
  --grad:#000 var(--s),transparent var(--s) calc(var(--s) + var(--g)),#000 0;
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-right:var(--b) solid;
  border-left:var(--b) solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to left ,var(--grad)) top,
    linear-gradient(to right,var(--grad)) bottom;
  background-size:100% var(--b);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text inside
</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:20px;--g:50%;--b:5px;">
Some text 
</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:80%;--g:10%;--b:1px">
Some text<br> inside
</div>
```

Another idea using clip-path:

```css
.box { 
  --b:2px;  /* Thickness of border */
  --g:10px; /* The gap */
  --s:10px; /* The offset of the gap */

  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:var(--b) solid;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, 
  
    calc(100% - var(--s) - var(--g)) 0,
    calc(100% - var(--s) - var(--g)) var(--b),
    calc(100% - var(--s))            var(--b),
    calc(100% - var(--s))            0,
  
    100% 0,100% 100%, 
    
    calc(var(--s) + var(--g)) 100%,
    calc(var(--s) + var(--g)) calc(100% - var(--b)),
    var(--s)                  calc(100% - var(--b)),
    var(--s)                  100%,
    
    0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text inside
</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:20px;--g:50%;--b:5px;">
Some text 
</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:80%;--g:10%;--b:1px">
Some text<br> inside
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution - would it be possible to make it responsive?

Comment: @peterxz what do you mean by *responsive*?

Comment: responsive to other resolutions and sizes - if you used this approach for a button that scales up, the gaps would be off

Comment: @peterxz it won't, you can test it

Comment: @peterxz use vw/% instead px eventually or a mix of both via calc()

Comment: @TemaniAfif the `linear-gradient` worked really well and i added media queries to adjust it based on our breakpoints. I am just playing around with `%` or `calc()`, but just wanted to mark this since it solved my problem.